# Dask DataFrame after Apply cannot reindex from a duplicate axis

Tags: dataframe, apply, dask, reindex, fillna

I'am trying to change nan values of item_price to the mean value based on item_id
in the following dask dataframe:

```
all_data['item_price'] = all_data[['item_id','item_price']].groupby('item_id')['item_price'].apply(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mean()))

All_data.head()
```

Unfortunately I get the following error:

```
ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis
```

Any idea how to avoid this error or any other way to change nan values to mean values for a dask dataframe?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to the problem. Fillna along with map can be used instead:

```
all_data['item_price'] = all_data['item_price'].fillna(
    all_data['item_id'].map(
        all_data.groupby('item_id')['item_price'].mean().compute()
    )
)
```

This gets rid of the duplicate axis problem. Beware you have to use compute as seen in the code inside the map function for it to work without an error.